# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError from Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online

Trying to get the details of a SharePoint site using a relative url.

GET /v1.0/sites/mytenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/mvep

However if the relative path is pointing to a site that does not exist I get a 500 Internal Server Error returned with the following json:
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UnknownError",
    "message": "Unknown Error",
    "innerError": {
        "request-id": "bc65a8a8-e857-4ece-9e1d-f42b5671f151",
        "date": "2018-12-05T11:44:13"
    }}

I tried same test against a demo tenant and the correct 404 / itemNotFound is returned.

There was a few posts here talking of a regression introduced back in Dec 2017 that was apparently fixed. 
Could this patch have been missed on our SPO servers?
Or is it a new regression?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tested again this morning and it now works as expected.